# Add Xaml hyperlink to rectangle

Tags: xaml, hyperlink

I am trying to add a hyperlink to a xaml rectangle and it's not working. I tried adding hyperlink with a button and it works. How can I add hyperlink to a group of rectangle for the code below.

How to give Hyperlink for below Code

```
<Rectangle Fill="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="38" Margin="1038,74,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="426"/>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1173,82,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Pending Sites " VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="24" Width="142" Foreground="#FFF7F6F1" FontSize="20" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" UseLayoutRounding="False" d:LayoutRounding="Auto">
                <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                    <CompositeTransform Rotation="-0.098"/>
                </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
            </TextBlock>
```

Code I tried with Button which is working fine

```
<Button Content="Click to go to desc page" Click="Button_Click_1" Margin="62,376,0,357"/>
 private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
           this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(dPlanner2x.MyPageDetails));
        }
```

Comment: What is 'not working'?  Can you not add the text to the rectangle, or not add the functionality that it does something when you click it?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why do you need the hyperlink for inside a rectangle, are you trying to make the rectangle clickable and navigate to a URI?

Comment: I am new to windows8 app development. I am trying to create a clickable Tile which navigates to another xaml page. I took a rectangle to create a tile design and trying to add clickable options to the tile. Please suggest me if my approach is wrong so that I can correct it. I appreciate your quick responses.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than trying to turn a `Rectangle` into a click-able object, you are much better off if you apply a `Style` to a `Button`.

An example of a `Style` to change the look of a `Button` is given below:

```
<Style x:Key="btnCommand" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border Name="rct" 
                        TextBlock.Foreground="White"
                        Background="DarkGray"
                        BorderBrush="DarkGray"
                        BorderThickness="1"
                        Cursor="Hand"
                        UseLayoutRounding="True"
                        SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                        Margin="10"
                        Height="24"
                        MinWidth="75">
                    <ContentPresenter TextBlock.FontStyle="Segoe UI Semibold"
                                      TextBlock.FontSize="14"/>
                </Border>

                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="rct"
                                Property="TextBlock.Foreground" 
                                Value="DarkGray" />
                        <Setter TargetName="rct"
                                Property="Background" 
                                Value="LightGray" />
                        <Setter TargetName="rct"
                                Property="BorderBrush" 
                                Value="DarkGray" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="rct"
                                Property="TextBlock.Foreground" 
                                Value="DarkGray" />
                        <Setter TargetName="rct"
                                Property="Background" 
                                Value="White" />
                        <Setter TargetName="rct"
                                Property="BorderBrush" 
                                Value="LightGray" />
                    </Trigger>

                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Obviously, you will want something that looks completely different, but the `Style` template above can be easily modified to fit your needs.